# categorization of reviews on playstore listing

Tags: google-play-store

recently i noticed that there is some count is displayed on review listed under the product listed on play store. The attached image is reviews of google Chrome browser for android. But the interesting thing is that it shows only when we are visiting play store from mobile device (using play store App). I thought it was categorized based on App versions, but on selecting the review, it will bring all reviews. The highlighted count was I am talking about. Does anybody have any idea?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: any idea of what? What's your actual question?

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear, my question is: what is this count denotes? it says "in 223 reviews", "in 256 reviews",  how this count is made? is this based on app version or anything?

Comment: Pretty sure the count is the number of reviews that used the bolded words (i.e. of all the reviews the app has, 2,152 used the word "useful"). They're basically showing you which words or phrases are most commonly used when describing the app. Don't have a source for that, though.